# Getting Error in spring boot with oauth2 i have all the in my project

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am getting below error, I have all the required jar in my project but still have getting same error, tried multiple ways but none of work for me.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["roles"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet[0]->org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUserAuthority["attributes"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap["auth_time"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1308)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnsupportedTypeSerializer.serialize(UnsupportedTypeSerializer.java:35)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:808)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:764)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:720)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:35)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:808)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:764)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:720)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:35)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:479)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:399)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1568)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)

I have stack : spring boot , sso with oauth2, sso provider is other team we are just injecting bunch off sso jar in our project.

I tried to resolved multiple ways mean tried to upgrade the jar for json serialize/deserialize lib but no luck , I am expecting how I do fixed this.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are getting this exception ?

Comment: *"I have all the required jar"* maybe yes, maybe not, and we can't know without your pom or gradle file. Your security configuration is required too (properties and beans)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.